# Return User Token instead of Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the php-sdk to create a session upon login of my site thru fb. Upon login, the user will be redirected to a file called fb_redirect.php. On that page, there is the following:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => '123456789',
                                    'secret' => '123456789',
                                    'cookie' => true));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
//$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token); // you do not need to set the token if there is one, so this should be conditional to if your switching tokens or setting a token from an external sdk.
```

When the

```
$access_token
```

is echoed here, it display the user token. But, on another page, I need to take advantage of the publish_actions permission that my app has requested and post a custom action to the user's timeline. For that to happen, I need the access token to be set to the user token. But, for some reason, on other pages the $access_token is always set to the access token and not the user token. How can I manually set it back to the user token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty method, this does not handle expiry.

```
if (!$_SESSION['fb_YourAppID_access_token']) {
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if ($access_token) {
$_SESSION['your_token'] = $access_token;
}
}else{
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_YourAppID_access_token'];
$_SESSION['your_token'] = $access_token;
}
```

this will look for existing token in browser, if not found it will ask the php sdk what the current token is, if there is a token in the sdk, it sets your session token to the current access token, if not it will save it blank.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the server-side flow, then you have to save it somewhere (a cookie, or a server-side session, or a DB table), and load it back when the user comes back.

Comment: You mean like manually insert it into the DB and query it when I need to use it again?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you have a way of identifying your users reliably, that'll work.

Comment: I just tried saving the user token as a session variable. It works on some page, I've noticed. For the one that it needs to be used in to post a custom action, however, it isn't displayed when echoed.

Comment: Then you most likely have a problem with your sessions. Did you use `session_start` in every page? Have you checked that the session id is passed correctly from on page to the next?